# Update QueryTable and export result as txt file using (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I try to export single sheet as .txt file after refreshing querytable.
I don't want to use `Workbooks.Add` or `.Copy and .PasteSpecial` method.
So far, I've made this:

```
Do Until i = 5
  With Sheets(2).QueryTables(1)
     .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With

  Sheets(2).SaveAs ThisWorkbook.path & filename & i & ".txt", _
  FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False

i = i + 1
Loop
```

On first loop this works great, but on second i get errors.

Comment: *i get errors* well, we can't read your mind, or your screen. What error do you get, and which line raises it?

Comment: Error is like this: No file access. The file may be corrupted, located on a server that is not responding, or read-only. I think after the first loop, the file is saved as txt and the code usage becomes unreasonable because xlsm no longer exists (`ThisWorkbook.path`).

Comment: You're missing a path separator, perhaps that is the problem.  Try `...SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & filename & i & ".txt"...`

Comment: Nah, its not that, I've made mistake in request. It should be: `Sheets(2).SaveAs ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & filename & i & ".txt", _
  FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False`

Comment: And it's definitely the `SaveAs` that's raising the error, not the `Refresh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I know what went wrong. Here is my original code:

```
Sub test()
Dim filename As String
Dim i As Integer
filename = "test_txt"
i = 0
Do Until i = 5
  With Sheets(2).QueryTables(1)
     .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With

  Sheets(3).SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\FOLDER\" & filename & i & ".txt", _
  FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False

i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Because i have `ThisWorkbook.Path` in loop, it changes every time I run it. Solution is simple - put `ThisWorkbook.Path` outsite the loop, like this:

```
Sub test()
Dim filename As String
Dim saveloc as String
Dim i As Integer
filename = "test_txt"
saveloc = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\FOLDER\"
i = 0
Do Until i = 5
  With Sheets(2).QueryTables(1)
     .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With

  Sheets(3).SaveAs saveloc & filename & i & ".txt", _
  FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False

i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Thanks @David Zemens for help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Sheets(2)` is part of `ThisWorkbook`, try the following:

```
Dim sep As String
sep = Application.PathSeparator

With ThisWorkbook
    Do Until i = 5
      .Sheets(2).QueryTables(1).Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
      .Sheets(2).SaveAs .path & sep & filename & i & ".txt", _
           FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False

      i = i + 1
    Loop
End With
```